# SeekToBegin fails when running as LocalSystem

Tags: c++, windows

The snippet of code below is used to download a file from a remote server. It works fine when run as a user or as an administrator but returns an error when run as LocalSystem (the requested operation is invalid). When we comment out the line fSourceFile->SeekToBegin(); the programs runs fine as LocalSystem.

Any insights into why we are getting this error? Should we worry about removing the statement: fSourceFile->SeekToBegin(); Any alternate approaches?

```
fSourceFile = (CHttpFile*)netSession.OpenURL(pwnd->m_strSource,1, 
                          INTERNET_FLAG_TRANSFER_BINARY | INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD);

// Get the starting time of the download(kb/sec calculation)
COleDateTime dlStart = COleDateTime::GetCurrentTime();

fSourceFile->SeekToBegin(); // Move cursor back to top for reading*/
```

Comment: It seems unlikely to be necessary to explicitly set the file pointer.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "runs fine **as LocalSystem**" - do you mean: "runs fine when the file is requested from localhost (127.0.0.1)"?

Comment: No. What I mean is when the program is run as a service with the highest Windows privileges: LocalSystem.